# How to open app chooser when clicking on a phone number?

Tags: cordova

In some apps when users click on a phone number, an app chooser pops out: call, skype, whatsapp, viber, the list depending on what apps are installed.

The same chooser is seen also when users click on an email address.

I can list contact phone numbers and contact id in phonegap.  How to make such a link?  Is it made by [cordova-webintent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent)?